# Pycharm debugger watch UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, encode

Versions are:

- PyCharm 2018.1.2 (Professional Edition)
- Python 2.7
- Python 3.6

test.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import sys

print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
d = {'中文': '中文'}
print(d)
```

When you run `python test.py`, the output is

```
ascii
{u'\u4e2d\u6587': u'\u4e2d\u6587'}
```

But will raise `UnicodeEncodeError` when `watch`ing it in debugger with Python2.7.

[image]

But it's normal when debuging it in Pycharm with Python3.6:

[image]

Comment: You may want to report this on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/